# Extending the SiteEditField method

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t, 2011-sp1

When using the default siteEditField function

```
@Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, Model.Component.Fields["Heading"])
```

And the field does not exist in the broker it generates an exception, that the field does not exist. What I expected was that the method

```
public static MvcHtmlString SiteEditField(this HtmlHelper helper, IComponent component, IField field, int index)
```

Would validate the input of value, if the field is empty or none existing to generate the siteedit tags for empty field.

How can this best be achieved; Extending the SiteEditHelper is not allowed since its a sealed class.

Comment: which version of DD4T are you using?

Answer (score 5):

You could create your own SiteEdit Extension methods helper which wrap the DD4T one e.g.

```
 public static class MySiteEditHelpers
 {
      public static MvcHtmlString SafeSiteEditField(this HtmlHelper helper, IComponent component, IField field)
      {
           if(field != null)
              return helper.SiteEditField(...)
           return new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);
      }
 }
```

(Alternatively || Additionally) you could raise this as an issue on the DD4T GitHub, fork the repo, fix it, and [submit a pull request for the next release](https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion)!